Audio_bevy: bevy doesn't replay audio after it finishes (Bevy 0.14.1)
I'm using bevy 0.14.1 to create a small game and I have some problems with the audio. In my game, there is a character that takes coin. Each time an user takes a coin, a sound must be played. I managed that the audio was played when the character took the first coin, but i couldn't make the audio be replayed again when the user takes another coin. Here's my code: What i did was an AudioBundle and i associated it to my entity(score):
impl Score {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self(0)
    }
}

let score_text = Text2dBundle {
        text: Text::from_section("0", text_style).with_justify(JustifyText::Left),
        transform: Transform::from_translation(POSITION_SCORE),
        ..default()
 };

let audio_score = AudioBundle {
        source: audio_asset.score.clone(),
        settings: PlaybackSettings {
            paused: true,
            mode: PlaybackMode::Once,
            ..default()
        },
    }; 

command.spawn((score_text, Score::new(), audio_score)); `
then i made a system to change the score and play the audio when it happens:
fn change_score(mut query: Query<(&mut Text, &mut Score, &AudioSink)>) {
    for(mut text, mut score_component, audio_sink) in  &mut query {
        if let Some(point) = text.sections.first_mut() {
            score_component.0 += 1;
            point.value = score_component.0.to_string();
           audio_sink.play();
        } 
    }
}

I realised that after audio_sink.play() is run and the sound is played, the sink is empty, i mean, the sink has no more audio to play.On the other hand, I know that change_score system is called as the number of point(score_component.0) is changed when an user takes a coin but the sound isn't replayed again.
Thank you.

Pretty sure you want to spawn an AudioBundle each time you want to play a sound.
